# WebView, back to appliaction (shouldOverrideUrlLoading VS JavascriptInterface)

Tags: android, webview

In my application

1. user click a button and a webview will open for payment
2. after payment user must back to application automatically

at first I use JavascriptInterface

```
@JavascriptInterface
        public void backtoapp() {


            ((mainac) getActivity()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    fm.popBackStack();

                }
            });



        }
```

and call backtoapp() like this

```
.
.
<body>
<script>
jint.backtoapp();
</script>
</body>
```

but I found new way to do this with shouldOverrideUrlLoading

```
webv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                if (url.startsWith("myapp://")) {

                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    fm.popBackStack();



                } 

                return true;
            }
.
.
```

and back to app with this

```
<?php
header("Location: myapp://openme");
?>
```

And I want to know which way is better and cross api > 15